# Открыть фото в браузере по ссылке/пути

Tags: python, requests

У меня такая задача:

Пользователь вводит ссылку на фото (либо указывает путь), фото должно скачаться, а потом открыться в браузере, как я могу это сделать?

```
import webbrowser
import requests
import pathlib
import urllib
import mimetypes


Name = input("Привет друг, как тебя зовут? ", )
Age = input(f"Приятно познакомиться {Name}, сколько тебе лет? ")
Username = input(f"Хорошо, раз тебе {Age}, можешь написать мне свой никнейм? ")
Photo = input(f"{Username}? Клёвый никнейм, но мой круче). Ладно, скинь мне любую фокту(либо ссылка, либо путь)")


def profile():
    f = open("profile.txt", "w")
    f.write(f"Имя-{Name}\nВозраст-{Age}\nНикнейм-{Username}\nВаша фотка-{Photo}")
    f.close()

profile()


img_data = requests.get(Photo).content
with open('image_name.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
   handler.write(img_data)



def open():
    webbrowser.open(f"{Photo}", new=0)

open()
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
import requests
import os
import webbrowser

browser = webbrowser.get('windows-default')
path = input("path/url")
if not os.path.exists(path):
    response = requests.get(path)
    with open("image.jpg", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)
    path = "image.jpg"

browser.open(path)
```

Comment: Это нужно добавить или это весь код?

Comment: Это часть кода, которая скачивает/открывает картинку (добавить)

Comment: Ты немного не понял. Моя задача состоит в том, что когда я отсылаю ссылку на фото, она скачивается, а после сохраняется в папке Images, а после открывается в браузере, где в адресной строке будет написано -file:///C:/Users/Raz0r/Desktop/image.jpg   . А второй вариант состоит в том, что вместо ссылки ты отсылаешь путь до фото(фото заранее на пк), а код просто открывает её в браузере  по пути. Задание не сложное, но т.к я занимаюсь питоном около 2х недель, мне сложно это сделать. Заранее извиняюсь за возможную грубость!